# Is it possible to send a URL from javascript running on the browser to the python program running on the client machine?

Tags: javascript, python

Can I send the url of the page from the javascript to the python program running on the client machine ??

Also can I redirect the output of the python program to the javascript to be displayed on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can if you're running a server with Python.

Create a simple server with python and return json. The only requirement is that the python server must be started in order to except requests.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use XMLHttpRequests you might run into problems that cross-domain requests are not permitted. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests for details. 
In case the 'send' action can be triggered by user input, e.g. clicking on a link or submitting a form, you can specify the Python server URL as the form action target or the href of the link.